# Rated power vs. temperature for resistors

Tags: power, resistors, temperature, pulse

As you know, there is a Rated power vs temperature curve for resistors in datasheets like the image below.
[image]

For DC inputs, I think everything is clear about power. My question is that for pulse inputs, should we use RMS power or average power to work with this curve. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Pulses are a whole separate section of the datasheet. If you have high power pulses at far above the DC limit but low repetition frequency, you cannot use average power. If the datasheet does not have a pulse section, then you should stay under the DC limit (or find another resistor).

For example, if you have a pulse which is 10x the rated power, but occurs infrequently, that pulse may still blow the resistor even if the average power calculation is below the limit in your curve.

For non-pulse waveforms that have a high repetition frequency, you can use the average power calculation. RMS power is not really what you want. You want to average the power over one full period of the waveform.

Here is a snapshot of a pulse repetition section from a pulse rated resistor.
(http://www.vishay.com/docs/20044/_crcw37.pdf)

[image]

Once you get to 100 seconds you are basically at the DC limit. But for 1us the resistor can dissipate 10,000x the DC limit.

Not all resistors are not going to be like that.

Comment: The linked datasheet doesn't mention "RMS power". The only "rms" in the datasheet is in the word "terms". I'll try and do the maths later to demonstrate what happens when you do an RMS calculation on a power waveform

Comment: @transitor, how about if I change the all the "rms"  terms to "average?"

Comment: That would probably be a good idea. I might try and put up a wiki post on "The RMS power problem" as it comes up frequently.

Comment: @Transistor I convinced myself you are right be considering the simple case of a 50% duty cycle square wave. If the power is 10 Watts during the "on"  time, then the average power is obviously 5 Watts. But the RMS power is around 7 Watts. That number, ~7 Watts, doesn't correspond to anything of any physical significance that I can see.

Comment: Correct. You've got the RMS of an RMS.

Comment: My problem was that I KNOW average power is what was wanted. I just thought that for power in a resistor, which is always positive, RMS and average are the same. Obviously that is wrong thinking on my part. Thanks for being patient and helping straighten me out.

Answer (score 0):

The power dissipated in an AC circuit (which pulsed current falls under) is calculated by using the RMS value of the voltage/current.

Some datasheets of resistors also show what energy / power can be applied for certain time, e.g. the RCH series of Vishay as shown below.

In other cases, one has to calculate/estimate the expcected raise in temperature.
For small durations, up to 1 ms, the heating is likely negligable. But for the obviously example having a pulse with duration of 60 seconds, and a frequency of 1 mHz, one should use the instantaneous current and duration rather than using the RMS current.

[image]